# MySQL gives an "Unknown column 'user.id' in 'field list'" error using Django's automatic id

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I have my `User` model set up with no primary key so that the automatic `id` will be used instead. However, when I try to access it using Django's "`_set`" notation when it is referenced through a foreign key:

```
def postDetails(request, pk)
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if post.user_set.all(): # Errors on this line
        [...]
```

I get an error from MySQL:

> OperationalError at /webApp/postDetail/42/ (1054,
>   "Unknown column 'user.id' in 'field list'")

What am I doing wrong? Should I be accessing it differently? Are there limitations to the automatic id?

Model for reference:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    blog = models.ForeignKey('Blog')
    active = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField()
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'post'
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class User(models.Model):
    level = models.ForeignKey(Level)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    note = models.CharField(max_length=4096)
    active = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'user'
```

Something else that I thought to include: I did run `syncdb` before running this.

Comment: Have you looked in the actual database to see if the field is in there?

Comment: Have you read about overriding the default user implementation?:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Comment: delete the columns in the db/ the db itself if `sqlite` and run `syncdb` again

Comment: @rslite Yes, and the field is not there. The `User` table is actually a mapping table in the actual implementation, with a joint primary key using `level` and `post`. I just changed the names because of company data. I think I should re-ask the question with the names closer to what they actually are, since it has garnered both downvotes and thrown off comments as is.

Comment: @petkostas The `User` model here was just a fake name to avoid putting out company info, so it doesn't really apply to me. Thank you for the suggestion though. I'll probably be re-asking the question using something clearer.

Comment: @tr33hous The `id` column never existed in the first place, so I can't  delete it.

Comment: What are the names of the db fields of the relation keys? Django expects to find a id field in your user table for the relation, and since you are using unmanaged tables you should be the one providing the field in the db, if your field is named something else, you need to specify it to django.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** : wrong answer. check comments below

The problem is that you have `managed` set to `False`. According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#managed)

> If False, no database table creation or deletion operations will be performed for this model. This is useful if the model represents an existing table or a database view that has been created by some other means. This is the only difference when managed=False. All other aspects of model handling are exactly the same as normal. This includes
>
> Adding an **automatic primary key field** to the model if you don’t declare it. To avoid confusion for later code readers, it’s recommended to specify all the columns from the database table you are modeling when using unmanaged models.

You will need to define the `primary key` as this is not done by default anymore.

Comment: Unless I'm reading it incorrectly, isn't the quoted text saying that the model being managed or unmanaged _doesn't_ matter for the automatic primary key creation? I can try it out to be sure, but according to what you quoted, it doesn't make a difference...

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but I think even though Django will add the id field to the model class, that field will not propagate to the DB with syncdb.

One way to try it would be to rename the existing User table, run syncdb and see if the User table is created. If not (which is likely because of the managed flag) try again with managed=True. If the id field appears in this case then my guess is you'll have to add it manually to the User table with the same parameters as the automatically created one.

Comment: Hm, the thing is, I can't add a column to the database. I thought that Django's automatic primary key would be something I could use within Django since I can't add an id to the database table. (The table's primary key is a multi-column primary key, so I can't add another, single column primary key)